# Bootstrap 3 DatePicker - How to reset selected date without resetting the picker configuration?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm trying to reset the selected date on button click, but so far I'm only able to clear the `input` element, without the actual date on the picker. The following code resets everything, including the configuration and the date, so its obviously not what I need.

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker('update',''); //resets everything
```

To elaborate: The user can only select a date 7 days from the current day. There's also a button that enables the user to clear the selected date from the picker, and select a new one. Right now, the clearing function can only clear the input element from the picker (but not the actual date in the picker element), or to clear the selection WITH the picker configuration (ex. the startDate: "+7d". I want to clear only the selected date, without resetting everything.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4L6fhjLf/)

This is what I came up with so far:

HTML:

```
<div id="myDatepicker" class="input-group date">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepick">
   <span class="input-group-addon">
   <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
   </span>
   <a href="#" id="duration_tag"></a>
</div>
<button type="button" id="clear">clear</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#clear").click(function(){
    $('#datepick').val(" ").datepicker({startDate: "+7d"});                  
});

$('#myDatepicker').datepicker({
                    startDate: "+7d",
                });

$('#myDatepicker').on('changeDate', function(e){
     $(this).datepicker('hide');
});

});
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific as it is hard to deduce what exactly you are trying to achieve..

Comment: Of course. The user can only select a date 7 days from the current day. There's also a button that enables the user to clear the selected date from the picker, and select a new one. Right now, the clearing function can only clear the input element from the picker (but not the actual date in the picker element), or to clear the selection WITH the picker configuration (ex. the `startDate: "+7d"`. I want to clear only the selected date, without resetting everything.

Comment: what reset actually means? Set date to current date or any other configuration. You can set datepicker to current date. $("#myDatepicker").datepicker("setDate", new Date());

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to get the current `datePicker` instance and call `setDate(null)` on it. you can do it like this:

```
$("#clear").click(function(){
  $('#myDatepicker').data('datepicker').setDate(null);
});
```

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4L6fhjLf/2/

Comment: Hi, as I know `#myDatepicker` is gather from HTML Id, so how about `datepicker` ? where to find the id/naming?

Comment: @mastersuse you choose your own id/naming. I referenced `#myDatepicker` because that's the id in the question

Answer (score 7):

```
$('#myDatepicker').data('DateTimePicker').date(null);
```

Comment: this is great and works bettter than `$("#myDatepicker").children().val('');`

Comment: Thank you so much it helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

For some reason neither of the above examples worked for me, but the following did:

```
$('#myDatepicker').data('DateTimePicker').clear(); // clears input value
```

which is effectively the same as [Dirk Vermeer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33734516/7573223) answer which did not work for what I was looking for.

I needed to also change the `viewMode` to start the picker process over, in my case this was decades you may need a different [viewMode](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#viewmode) option:

```
$('#myDatepicker').data('DateTimePicker').clear().viewMode('decades')
```