# Clear(reset) date month and year of bootstrap-datepicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using bootstrap-datepicker and want to reset date month and year.
I found solution just for clearing the date:

```
$('#datepicker').val('').datepicker('update');
```

Do you have idea how can I clear month and year?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3 DatePicker - How to reset selected date without resetting the picker configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31003648/bootstrap-3-datepicker-how-to-reset-selected-date-without-resetting-the-picker)

Comment: Well, as I can see from there nothing works for me.

Answer (score 2):

ANSWER:

I finaly found it:

```
var today = new Date(); //this is in format DD.MM.YYYY
var date = today.getDate() + '.' + (today.getMonth() + 1) + '.' + today.getFullYear();
$('#datepicker-wrapper').datepicker('update', date);
```